# Setting up SFML on Ubuntu 13.04 and QT-Creator

Tags: qt, ubuntu, compilation, sfml

I've been trying to get SFML to work with QT-creator (and gcc in general) but my example projects won't compile. I installed it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

But compiling just gives me a lot of errors:

```
/home/jan/Documents/SFMLTest/main.cpp:5: error: undefined reference to sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'

/home/jan/Documents/SFMLTest/main.cpp:5: error: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
```

and etc.

My .Pro file is setup like this:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
```

and this is inside main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

I tried doing [this](http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/building-sfml-2-0-with-make-for-gcc/) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be great as I'm still quite new to linux/ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package provided with Ubuntu is very old and the API have changed much since then (there was no `sf::CircleShape` for example). I suggest you build it yourself. Download it from http://sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.0/ and execute the following:

```
cmake
sudo make install
```

To tweak configurations, install `cmake-qt-gui` and execute `cmake-gui` instead of `cmake`.

It may complain about not found dependencies, just install what it says is missing with apt-get. (It might be easier to find the exact package name with `synaptic`)

For more details: http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php

Comment: Also note that the version in the Ubuntu repositories is 1.6 while current version is 2.0, this matters for the documentation and examples.